# Programatically change Button content in Style

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

In my application I am using a style to a listbox. In that style there is a button. I want to change the content of the button. The xaml shows below

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                            <Button Content="Load More..." Name="btnLoadMore" Click="btnLoadMore_Click"></Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How can I programmatically change the button content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to that Dependency Property to flow whatever between the UI & the data object. A good explanation can be found in the [docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) reagarding Data Binding and multiple tutorials available. Hope this helps.